# Bucket a continuous variable into distinct boundary buckets

Tags: sas, pyspark

How to bucket continuous variables into fixed number of buckets such that the boundaries don't overlap?

Ex : Lets say I have 500 numbers with 302 1s, 120 2s and a bunch of other values that range from 3 - 40. How do I bucket these into 5 bins without looking at the distribution?

Percentile buckets would mean 1s present in 1,2 & 3 buckets while they are all effectively just one bin.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using. one of the cluster analysis procedures (e.g. `proc fastclus`), requesting 5 1-d clusters.

Answer (score 0):

Use PROC RANK with GROUPS to specify the number of groups. You can also specify some methods, but they're all percentile based.